# Fullscreen buttons are not working in Expo webview

Tags: react-native, expo, android-webview

I have made a simple Expo webview app. But when I load **youtube or other video websites** in the app it **disables the fullscreen button** automatically. Suppose I played a video in youtube web and I click on the fullscreen button it doesn't even work. Is there any way to fix it?

*Here is my simple code:*

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}> 
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'https://google.com' }}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Fullscreen button should work while pressing inside the webview.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube fullscreen button is disabled in Expo WebView by default for security reasons. This is because the WebView component does not have access to all of the same features as a native browser, such as the ability to control the device's orientation. As a result, if the YouTube fullscreen button were enabled, it would be possible for a malicious website to take control of the user's device and display fullscreen content without their consent.

However, there is a way to enable the YouTube fullscreen button in Expo WebView. To do this, you need to set the allowsFullscreenVideo prop to true. This can be done in the following ways:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}> 
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'https://google.com' }}
        allowsFullscreenVideo={true} //this line adds fullscreen view functionality
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```